# Dynamically add reqired attribute to input fields in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, validation, required

I am not able to dynamically set required attribute to input fields
My form's required attribute has to change dynamically based on a radio button field.

This is how the form looks when the radio button is set as wants to join [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Sbn.png). and when radio button is set as member/alumnus the form looks like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDqUX.png)

I am not able to dynamically switch the required attribute for input fields in respective forms.

This is the code for contact and DOB field if new Member is checked

```
    <label class="control-label is-imp"></label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="radio" ng-model="joinFormData.joinType" value="wantsToJoin">I Want to join as member
                                    <input type="radio" ng-model="joinFormData.joinType" value="alreadyMember">I am a member/alumnus
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group no-pad-left" ng-if="joinFormData.joinType == 'wantsToJoin'">
                                <div class="nss-only" ng-if="clubType == 'NSS'">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-12 no-pad-left no-pad-right">
                                        <div class="col-md-6 no-pad-left">
                                            <label class="control-label is-imp">Contact:</label> 
                                            <input
                                                type="text" class="form-control" id="body_contact"
                                                name="body_contact" ng-model="joinFormData.contact" placeholder="1234567890" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{10}$/" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="10" integer [ng-required]="joinFormData.joinType == 'wantsToJoin'">
                                            <span ng-show="joinForm.body_contact.$error.$invalid || joinForm.body_contact.$error.pattern"><span class = "red-color">Enter a valid number!</span></span>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-6 no-pad-right">
                                            <label class="control-label is-imp">DOB:</label> 
                                            <input
                                                type="date" class="form-control" id="body_dob"
                                                name="body_dob" ng-model="joinFormData.dob"
                                                required ng-maxlength="100" required>
                                            <span ng-show="joinForm.body_dob.$error.required && joinForm.body_dob.$touched"><span class="red-color">Required!</span></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> </div> </div>
```

This is the code for select type field if Member/ Alumnus is checked

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12 no-pad-left no-pad-right">
                                <div class="col-md-6 no-pad-left" ng-if="joinFormData.joinType == 'alreadyMember'">
                                    <label class="control-label is-imp">I am already a member/alumnus:</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <select ng-model="joinFormData.memberType"
                                            class="form-control selectpicker" [required]="joinFormData.joinType == 'alreadyMember'" name="body_type">
                                            <option value="" selected disabled>Select Type</option>
                                            <option value="member">Member</option>
                                            <option value="alumni">Alumni</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <!-- <span ng-if="!joinForm.body_type.$valid && joinForm.body_type.$touched"><span class="red-color">Required!</span></span> -->
                                    </div>
                                </div></div>
```

I tried using [required]="joinFormData.joinType == 'alreadyMember'" conditions but that didn't work.

Kindly help me out. I am not able to figure out the mistake as i am new to angular

Comment: You're using Angular syntax in AngularJS. These are two different frameworks, with a different syntax. All you need is `ng-required="joinFormData.joinType == 'wantsToJoin'"`. Read the **correct** documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/

Comment: I even tried the same for the Contact field but the submit button got validated even if the contact field was not entered

Comment: This is the sumbit button code

Comment: <button type="submit" ng-style="joinFormData.declaration ? {'cursor': 'pointer'} : {'cursor': 'not-allowed'}" class="btn btn-default btn-save-custom"  ng-click="joinLeap()" ng-disabled="joinForm.$invalid" >Submit</button>

Comment: Yes your answer works ...I removed the [ ] for ng-required. Thanks a lot @JBNizet